# ASP .NET Core MVC Model not represented in View

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So my situation is that I am populating a model based on a text box in my view. My code is this

View:

```
@model LiteModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>Lite ID</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LiteId)
    <br />
    <label>Width</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BaseSize);
    <br />
    <label>Height</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HeightSize);
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="right" />
    <br />
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FromForm]LiteModel model)
    {
        model = LoadLiteInfo(model);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Model:

```
namespace LiteViewer.Models
{
    public class LiteModel
    {
        public string LiteId { get; set; }

        public string ShapeId { get; set; }

        public double BaseSize { get; set; }

        public double HeightSize { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I know the LoadLiteInfo method works as its supposed to, it populates the model object just as it should. For some reason however the changes in the model are not being reflected in the view. I cant for the life of my figure out why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making changes to the posted model you need to call `ModelState.Clear()`.

Comment: So i tried just using a new model as your code sample suggested. However it didnt make any difference. But once I tried the ModelState.Clear() worked like a charm.

Comment: OK, I will edit my answer to remove the bit about constructing a new model.